# QGIS-Server and Virtualhost: Problems

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, apache

Following the official guide to install QGIS-Server 3.22
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-debian-based-systems

I install without problems QGIS and QGIS-Server (and Apache).

Eventually though when I go to test the site:
http://178.128.200.12/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

my browser can't find anything.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I am attaching the procedure I followed:
https://vittorioemanueleiervolino.notion.site/GIS-Hosting-1ebfb14bd3764e63acda6e707a24317b

Comment: Where is the qgs map file with all the configuration? is it referenced by the Apache config automatically? if not you will need to add the local path to its location using a map parameter, something like http://178.128.200.12/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=/path/to/config.qgs

Comment: Hi, I think you are close. Using your same URL without cgi-bin (http://178.128.200.12/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) does show 403 Forbidden. You should check permissions for `/home/qgis/projects` folder (775) and `world.qgs` (664).